# Calling function with explicit user defined cast operator is ambigous

Tags: c++, casting

I encounter an issue, that is hard to explain for me. Here is the minimal, reproducible code, that is failing on both GCC 6.2 and Clang 3.9:

```
class T2;

class T1
{
    int field1;
public:
    T1(int pf) : field1(pf) {}
    operator int() { return field1; }
    operator T2();
};

class T2
{
    int field2;
public:
    T2(int pf) : field2(pf) {} 
};

T1::operator T2() { return T2(field1); }

void foo(T2 pt) {}

int main()
{
    T1 obj1(1);
    T2 obj2(2);

    foo((T2) obj1);             // ambiguous conversion for C-style cast from 'T1' to 'T2'
    foo(T2(obj1));              // ambiguous conversion for functional-style cast from 'T1' to 'T2'
    foo(static_cast<T2>(obj1)); // ambiguous conversion for static_cast from 'T1' to 'T2'
}
```

Note that I didn't write the specific constructor to convert from T1 to T2, so I guess it should be all clear to the compiler, that the only way is to use user defined cast operator.

The curious fact is that when I comment out a seemingly unrelated cast operator:

```
// operator int() { return field1; }
```

then the code compiles hassle-free. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Interestingly enough, implicit cast (i.e. foo(obj1)) works fine.

Comment: @Dmitry implicit works because it must select operator T2, which requires only one implicit conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(T2) obj1` means exactly the same thing as `T2(obj1)` (or `static_cast<T2>(obj1)` in this case), but maybe it'll be easier to reason about this constructor-like syntax.

With the code as-is, there are two options:

- construct `T2` with an `int`, obtained by the user-defined conversion operator to `int`
- construct `T2` from `T2` obtained by the user-defined conversion operator to `T2`

As per N4140:

> If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than
>   all other viable functions, then it is the one selected by overload
>   resolution; otherwise the call is ill-formed
>
> Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are
>   indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following
>   rules applies:
>
> - User-defined conversion sequence `U1` is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence `U2` if they
>     contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or
>     they initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization and in
>     either case the second standard conversion sequence of `U1` is better
>     than the second standard conversion sequence of `U2`.

Since this doesn't apply, neither conversion is better than the other.

Comment: Why does it need to construct `T2` from `T2`? Why doesn't it use that value directly?

Comment: @Danh the call to `foo` only obfuscates the problem. If you take it out, it's ill-formed to just perform the cast, without even passing the resultant `T2` value anywhere. [link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eZD4Y7jedPg1FwGk)